# Does load next page on PFQueryTableViewController count as a server request?

Tags: parse-platform

I'm considering creating an alternative to PFQueryTableViewController because I need some functionality that isn't offered.

I'm curious if the Load Next Page button on PFQueryTableViewController results in a server call?

...because in my implementation I'm going to run a query each time I need to load another page.  I'm hoping that this won't be more expensive than PFQueryTableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

When `queryForTable` is called it keeps a record of how many objects of that queried class are needed to display in the PFQTVC. The count is updated every time `loadNextPage` is called and loads the necessary data to fill the remaining `objectsPerPage` that you set for the PFQTVC. If there are more objects that could be loaded into the table, the PFQTVC can create a custom "Load More Cell" to load the next page, or remain content. So by having to update the table for next page and someone add a new post on a twitter like app for example, it would need to request that data because its new.